# Indy TIdHTTP changes my authorization header from bearer to basic?

Tags: delphi, https, authorization, indy, delphi-xe7

Delphi XE7 and Indy 10:

I am trying to communicate with a rest server that requires 
**Authorization:Bearer xxxxxxx** 
in the header of the HTTP call

I am doing the following in my code:

```
  ...
  https.Request.Clear;    
  https.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
  https.Request.BasicAuthentication:=false;    
  https.Request.Accept:='application-json';    
  https.Request.ContentType:='application/json';    
  token :=get_access_token;   
  Https.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Authorization', 'Bearer '+token);   
  json :=https.post(base_api,reqjson);
```

Just before POST then content of request.headers is

> (nil, [], $31F28C0, #0, '', #0, False, 0, nil, True,
>   (('**Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxx...x'**, nil), ('', nil), ('',
>   nil), ('', nil)), 1, 4, False, dupIgnore, False, (nil,nil), (nil,nil),
>   False, ': ', True, True, 2147483647, QuoteHTTP)

But when I check idlog debug it shows:

> POST xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> Content-Type: application/json
>
> Content-Length: 629
>
> **Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxx...xxx**
>
> Host: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> Accept: application-json
>
> Accept-Encoding: identity
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)

It seems as Bearer is changed into Basic ?? How do I avoid this ?

Comment: try with `Https.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'Bearer ' + token;`

Comment: Also set `Https.Request.CustomHeaders.FoldLines := False;`. Since you are using an older Delphi version, it may be worthwhile to upgrade to the [latest indy version](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx).

Comment: Tried both, no change, by the way, I am using openSLL, don't know if this is important.

Comment: Then I guess your Indy version is too old and you will have to upgrade... (unless the code you have shown isn't your real code and the problem is somewhere else, which I guess why your question has been downvoted) Always include an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Figured the problem out myself. It seems that when I do not allocate the HTTP component dynamically, some left overs are in the component from previous calls, that somehow disable the change of the Authorization field. After I changed it to a "fresh" dynamically allocated http component, it worked. Thanks  for your effort. It was really fast

Comment: @IbElfving `TIdHTTP` generates a `Basic` header only if the server asks for `Basic`, or if `Request.BasicAuthentication=True` (it is not in your case). If you don't use a dynamic instance, when you clear the `Request` each time, you can also free-and-nil the `Request.Authentication` property so it doesn't carry over. Or, at least,set `Request.Connection='close'` so the connection is closed after the response is sent. `TIdHTTP` frees the `Request.Authentication` when the socket is closed and authentication had completed (in case authentication uses multiple requests over several connections).

Comment: @IbElfving FYI, there is a new `TIdBearerAuthentication` class in the works, so users won't have to resort to using the `CustomHeaders` property anymore to send bearer tokens over HTTP.

Comment: Thanks for the info Remy. Sounds promising. My problem was lazyness. Quick and dirty testing